# Can I download a lazy load image?

Tags: python, html, xpath, lazy-loading, urllib

I'm trying to download some images from tripadvisor using urllib but all that I get for the url in the src field from the html is [this](http://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif)

I've done some research and I found out that those are lazy load images... Is there any way to download them??

Comment: The link you gave doesn't work

Comment: I'm sorry try with this https://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurant_Review-g3174493-d3164947-Reviews-Le_Ciaspole-Tret_Fondo_Province_of_Trento_Trentino_Alto_Adige.html

Comment: You could use a hyperlink or you could left click and go to inspect and then find that picture in the element page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract a list of images from Javascript using the [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) modules, then iterate over the list and retrieve the images you are interested in.

**EDIT:**

The problem was that the images have the same name, so they got overwritten. Fetching the first three images is trivial, but references to the other images in the carousel are not loaded until the carousel is opened, so that's trickier. For some images you can find a higher resolution version by substituting "photo-s" in the path with "photo-w", but figuring out which requires diving deeper into Javascript logic.

```
import urllib, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def img_data_filter(tag):
    if tag.name == "script" and tag.text.strip().startswith("var lazyImgs"):
        return True
    return False

response = urllib.urlopen("https://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurant_Review-g3174493-d3164947-Reviews-Le_Ciaspole-Tret_Fondo_Province_of_Trento_Trentino_Alto_Adige.html")
soup = bs(response.read(), 'html.parser')
img_data = soup.find(img_data_filter)

js = img_data.text
js = js.replace("var lazyImgs = ", '')
js = re.sub(r";\s+var lazyHtml.+", '', js, flags=re.DOTALL)

imgs = json.loads(js)
suffix = 1

for img in imgs:
    img_url = img["data"]

    if not "media/photo-s" in img_url:
        continue

    img_name = img_url[img_url.rfind('/')+1:-4]
    img_name = "%s-%03d.jpg" % (img_name, suffix)
    suffix += 1

    urllib.urlretrieve(img_url, img_name)
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to download a couple images for the restaurant.

Comment: Your algorithm gets only one of them... The one with the link "Tutte le foto dei visitatori"... Can you explain to me how to get the first 3 or 4 of them? And why your algorithm doesn't download them? Aren't they images too?

Comment: Thank you very much... Actually I've already adjusted it myself but your I think your edit is better.